# align 2 images side by side and make their caption underneath them

Tags: html, css

I need help making these 2 images displayed side by side, and I want the text to be underneath the images not beside it. the problem even when I make these two images display one beside one for some reason the caption come on the right of each image. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

HTML:

```
  <div class="container">
    <figure id="img-div1">
      <img id="image1" src="https://www.wearethemighty.com/app/uploads/legacy/assets.rbl.ms/17317425/origin.jpg" alt="Sadam husain In his reign" style="width:50%" background-size="cover">
      <figcaption id="img-caption">
        A drawing for Sadam husain represents the period of his reign.
      </figcaption>
    </figure>
  </div>

  <div class="container2">
    <figure id="img-div2">
      <img id="image2" src="https://arc-anglerfish-arc2-prod-advancelocal.s3.amazonaws.com/public/MIE5YDG625EFNGPHMVLSL3JDKM.jpg" style="width:40%" align=flex background-size=cover>
      <figcaption id="img-caption">
        Sadam husain inside the court.
      </figcaption>
    </figure>
  </div>
```

CSS:

```
.container {
  display: inline-flex;
}

img {
  max-width: 200%;
  height: auto;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

#img-div1 {
  background: white;
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 0;
  display: inline;
}

#img-div2 {
  background: white;
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 0;
  display: flex;
  float: inline;
}

#img-caption {
  margin: 10px 0 5px 0;
}

b @media (max-width: 460px) {
  #img-caption {
    font-size: 1.4rem;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an updated solution, though not the most elegant, but I tried to keep as much of your original markup and css as possible.  I also added a media query for smaller screens.  This solution uses static widths in order to have some parity between the two photos....I don't think using `img` is ever going to give you the desired result.

Make sure to run 'full page'...there is a media query in there that will stack images in smaller viewports.

```css
 .container {
            display: inline-flex;
        }

        @media (max-width: 900px) {
            .container {
                display: flex;
                flex-direction: column;
            }
        }


        #img-div1 {
            background: white;
            margin: 0 24px;
            background-image: url("https://www.wearethemighty.com/app/uploads/legacy/assets.rbl.ms/17317425/origin.jpg");
            background-size: cover;
            width: 550px;
            height: 300px;
        }

        #img-div2 {
            background: white;
            margin: 0 24px;
            background-image: url("https://arc-anglerfish-arc2-prod-advancelocal.s3.amazonaws.com/public/MIE5YDG625EFNGPHMVLSL3JDKM.jpg");
            background-size: cover;
            width: 550px;
            height: 300px;
        }

        #img-caption {
            margin: 10px 0 5px 0;
            text-align: center;
        }

        @media (max-width: 460px) {
            #img-caption {
                font-size: 1.4rem;
            }
        }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport"
        content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no, shrink-to-fit=no" />
   
</head>

<body>

    <div class="container">
        <figure>
            <div id="img-div1">
            </div>
            <div id="img-caption">
                A drawing for Sadam husain represents the period of his reign.
            </div>
        </figure>
        <figure>
            <div id="img-div2">
            </div>
            <div id="img-caption">
                Sadam husain inside the court.
            </div>
        </figure>
    </div>
</body>


</html>
```

Comment: Thank you so much, this code solved the problem. However, could you please advise how to remove the gap / space between these 2 images? You can see the gap in this screenshot   https://i.ibb.co/z2Ch4mG/image.png

Comment: yes, you can reduce the margins....just change `margin: 0 24px;` to `margin: 0;`.  By the way...I know you wanted to keep your markup as is, more or less, but you could create a much more elegant solution with a proper 2 column flexbox layout, or even a 2 column layout with css grid.  Both are worth a bit of research, you will likely find either technique very useful.

Comment: change margin to 0 not remove the space between images, as you can see here  https://prntscr.com/227cjda . However, I will keep searching for flexibox layout, thank you

Answer (score 1):

There are lots of techniques but a simple solution is just `display: inline-flex;`. see snippet below.

```css
body {
      font-family: sans-serif;
    }

    .container {
      display: inline-flex;
      text-align: center;
    }

    img {
      max-width: 100%;
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport"
    content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no, shrink-to-fit=no" />

</head>

<body>

  <div class="container">
    <figure>
      <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/1pXOL.jpg" alt="">
      <figcaption>
        BUNNY
      </figcaption>
    </figure>

    <figure>
      <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/HRwWf.jpg" alt="">
      <figcaption>
        DOG
      </figcaption>
    </figure>
  </div>

</body>


</html>
```

Comment: The images overlapping one over the other, can you please advice how to make them side by side?

Comment: Can you try giving the images a static width?  `<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/HRwWf.jpg" alt="" width="300">` for instance...

Comment: Unfortunately, static width does not solve the problem. It is cropping the image! Have a look for the images now https://prnt.sc/21rmvr6. They are supposed to be side by side, and the caption under them.  Also, you can see the full code here : https://codepen.io/aldelemy/pen/QWqwJOz

Comment: I think based on what you are trying to accomplish, with images of varying dimensions, you might want to consider creating two side by side divs, and src the images with `background-image`, and then set `background-size` to `cover`.

Comment: Thank you for your support. I did as you advised, but still I have a problem. You can see the result from this screenshot: https://prnt.sc/21wvixd   I have updated the above code and added the full real code. Now you can see the error in the code, and you can see how I am a beginner

Comment: I think I didn't explain it properly....`background-size: cover;` doesn't work on an `img` tag...it works in conjunction with `background-image`.  I'll take your updated code and provide another answer.

Answer (score 0):

Ok here's another solution, in addition to the one above.  With a few small tweaks you can use css grid and it will give you a bit more flexibility and I think more in line with what you were trying to do?

You'll need to add a media query to stack in smaller screens but for larger screens you should get the side by side.

```css
.grid {
  grid-column: 1 / -1;
  grid-gap: 0;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 550px 550px;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
}


   
#img-div1 {
  background: white;
  background-image: url("https://www.wearethemighty.com/app/uploads/legacy/assets.rbl.ms/17317425/origin.jpg");
  background-size: cover;
  width: 550px;
  height: 300px;
}

#img-div2 {
  background: white;
  background-image: url("https://arc-anglerfish-arc2-prod-advancelocal.s3.amazonaws.com/public/MIE5YDG625EFNGPHMVLSL3JDKM.jpg");
  background-size: cover;
  width: 550px;
  height: 300px;
}

#img-caption {
  margin: 10px 0 5px 0;
  width: 550px;
  text-align: center;
}

@media (max-width: 460px) {
  #img-caption {
  font-size: 1.4rem;

  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>

    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport"
            content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no, shrink-to-fit=no" />
       
    </head>

    <body>

        <div class="grid">
            <figure>
                <div id="img-div1">
                </div>
                <div id="img-caption">
                    A drawing for Sadam husain represents the period of his reign.
                </div>
            </figure>
            <figure>
                <div id="img-div2">
                </div>
                <div id="img-caption">
                    Sadam husain inside the court.
                </div>
            </figure>
        </div>
    </body>


    </html>
```